# Java Write to File Perfomance

Tags: java, performance, io-redirection

i am trying to write to file with redirection from command line.
my programm is very slow when i read a file of 25MB and 90% of execution time spent in "System.out.println" .I tried some other methods than System.out.print but coulnt fix..

which method i have to use to print a big ArrayList? (with redirection)

i would appreciate your help and an example
thanks

here is my code:

```
public class Ask0 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int i = 0, token0, token1;
        String[] tokens;
        List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input;

        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tokens = input.split("\\|");
            inputList.add(tokens[0] + "|" + tokens[1]);
            token0 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            token1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

            List<Integer> l = map.get(token0);

            if (l == null) {
                l = new ArrayList<>();
                map.put(token0, l);
            }

            if (l.contains(token1) == false) {
                l.add(token1);
            }

            i++;
        }

        i = 0;

        for (int j = inputList.size(); j > 0; j--) {
            tokens = inputList.get(i).split("\\|");
            token0 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            token1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            List l = map.get(token0);
            System.out.println(tokens[0] + "|" + tokens[1] + "[" 
                    + (l.indexOf(token1) + 1) + "," + l.size() + "]");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
3|78 4|7765 3|82 2|8 4|14 3|78 2|8 4|12
```

**Desired result**

```
 3|78[1,2] 4|7765[1,3] 3|82[2,2] 2|8[1,1] 4|14[2,3] 3|78[1,2] 2|8[1,1] 4|12[3,3]
```

Comment: Are the 90% spent in the println istelf or in the 7 String concatenations?

Comment: Can you post `input` example?

Comment: i dont know to be honest :)  how can i make my programm faster?

Comment: @Pan.Stav By knowing what you want to accomplish, thus finding an example to prove what's slowing you down. It looks like your first loop creates parses a list of strings with format "a|b" and populates a key-value-store with that. Then you loop again through all lines, parse everything again, just to print a reformatted input string. What's the purpose of your program?

Comment: for a sample input:3|78
4|7765
3|82
2|8
4|14
3|78
2|8
4|12

Comment: @Pan.Stav Post a data set that is causing you performance issues and from there it could be possible to help you.

Comment: i want the out put:3|78[,2]
4|7765[,3]
3|82[,2]
2|8[,1]
4|14[,3]
3|78[,2]
2|8[,1]
4|12[,3]

Comment: You may consider using BufferedPrintWriter over the System.out. If you are writing to a console, that may be painfully slow by itself

Comment: Please add information in the question itself, by using the [edit] link. Remember to format any code so that it can be readable, using the `{}` button when editing your question. Please explain what your program is supposed to do, and the data that causes problems.

Comment: @Pan.Stav Doesn't even work with the input you provided

Comment: output:3|78[1,2]
4|7765[1,3]
3|82[2,2]
2|8[1,1]
4|14[2,3]
3|78[1,2]
2|8[1,1]
4|12[3,3]

Comment: `System.out` flushes every line, As gusto suggested an additional larger buffer, maybe also direct to a file would speed up the most. Then Integer.parseInt here is not needed I think. `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map ... new HashSet()` would be more direct. Finally style: `X == false` should be written as `!X ` ("not X").

Comment: @gusto2 I tried but my program was same slow maybe I don’t get right how it works and I couldn’t find how I do redirection with fileWriter... i want to choose the file which I m going to write from cmd

Comment: You should use Buffered NIO2 output for file writing , ans StringBuffer  for concate stings faster

Comment: @hgregoire `StringBuilder` is faster than `StringBuffer` if you only use it in one thread.

Comment: @Pan.Stav Your input doesn't match your code. Your input is space-separated, your code expects newline-separated. Which do you want?

Comment: @Pan.Stav, are you seeing the slowdown when you are actually piping the output into another process? Printing the the output stream will be as fast as the process consuming it. If you print to the terminal, however, the terminal will waste a lot of time doing line processing and lead to a slower performance. Try piping it into another process that doesn't print to the screen and see how well it performs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed, the below code:

- Uses a `StringBuilder` for fast concatenation into a resulting `String` and fast output since only one massive `String` is printed at the end, saving unnecessary buffer flushes.
- Doesn't create a bunch of `String`s when parsing the input, just a small `byte[]` and `Integer`s in an `ArrayList`.
- Manually uses a 64kiB buffer for reading.
- Doesn't rejoin the tokens with `"|"` in the middle only to split them again later.
- Uses a `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>` instead of a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` to save time on element lookups in the list (turns algorithm from O(n<sup>2</sup>) time to O(n) time).

Some speedups that might not work as you want:

- Doesn't waste time properly handling Unicode.
- Doesn't waste time properly handling negative or overflowed numbers.
- Doesn't care what the separator characters are (you could input `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` instead and it would still work just like `"1|2\n3|4\n5|6\n"`).

You can [see that it gives the correct results for your test input here](https://ideone.com/qSy3Ue#stdin) (except that it separates the outputs by newlines like in your code).

```java
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;

private static enum InputState { START, MIDDLE }

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Input the numbers
    final byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    final List<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

    int inputValue = 0;
    InputState inputState = InputState.START;

    while (true) {
        int j = 0;
        final int bytesRead = System.in.read(inputBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (bytesRead == -1) {
            if (inputState == InputState.MIDDLE) {
                inputs.add(inputValue);
            }
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
            byte ch = inputBuffer[i];
            int leftToken = 0;
            if (ch < 48 || ch > 57) {
                if (inputState == InputState.MIDDLE) {
                    inputs.add(inputValue);
                    inputState = InputState.START;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (inputState == InputState.START) {
                    inputValue = ch - 48;
                    inputState = InputState.MIDDLE;
                }
                else {
                    inputValue = 10*inputValue + ch - 48;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.in.close();

    // Put the numbers into a map
    final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size();) {
        final Integer left  = inputs.get(i++);
        final Integer right = inputs.get(i++);

        final Map<Integer, Integer> rights;
        if (map.containsKey(left)) {
            rights = map.get(left);
        }
        else {
            rights = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(left, rights);
        }

        rights.putIfAbsent(right, rights.size() + 1);
    }

    // Prepare StringBuilder with results
    final StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size();) {
        final Integer left  = inputs.get(i++);
        final Integer right = inputs.get(i++);

        final Map<Integer, Integer> rights = map.get(left);

        results.append(left).append('|').append(right);
        results.append('[').append(rights.get(right)).append(',');
        results.append(rights.size()).append(']').append('\n');
    }

    System.out.print(results);
}
```

You can alternatively manually use a 64 kiB `byte[]` output buffer with `System.out.write(outputBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite); System.out.flush();` as well if you want to save memory, though that's a lot more work.

Also, if you know the minimum and maximum values that you'll see, you can use `int[]` or `int[][]` arrays instead of `Map<Integer, Integer>` or `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>`, though that's somewhat more involved as well. It would be very fast, though.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! it was really very helpful! i had also done a second implementation with Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>> but couldnt fix another things that improove perfomance which is my main concern.  but your answer covered everythink  and gave solution to my problem!